# MongooseIm Rest API connection issue with local Setup

Tags: api, rest, curl, swagger, mongoose-im

I have setup the mongooseim [3.3.0] ubuntu 14.04 & it works perfect with android client setup. Then I need to test the REST API for creating room , Then I have got this error when running the swagger documentation.

```
curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic dXNlcjpwYXNzd29yZA==' 'http://localhost:8089/api/rooms'

curl: (52) Empty reply from server
```

This is the mongooseim configs which related to REST API.

```
{ 8089 , ejabberd_cowboy, [
      {num_acceptors, 10},
      {transport_options, [{max_connections, 1024}]},
      {protocol_options, [{compress, true}]},
      {ssl, [{certfile, "priv/ssl/fake_cert.pem"}, {keyfile, "priv/ssl/fake_key.pem"}, {password, ""}]},
      {modules, [
          {"_", "/api/sse", lasse_handler, [mongoose_client_api_sse]},
          {"_", "/api/messages/[:with]", mongoose_client_api_messages, []},
          {"_", "/api/contacts/[:jid]", mongoose_client_api_contacts, []},
          {"_", "/api/rooms/[:id]",    mongoose_client_api_rooms, []},
          {"_", "/api/rooms/[:id]/config",    mongoose_client_api_rooms_config, []},
          {"_", "/api/rooms/:id/users/[:user]",    mongoose_client_api_rooms_users, []},
          {"_", "/api/rooms/[:id]/messages",    mongoose_client_api_rooms_messages, []}
      ]}
  ]}
```

This is the swagger document I have referred. https://mongooseim.readthedocs.io/en/3.3.0/swagger/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed the following things:

1. The `curl` example you provided tries to send the request to MongooseIM over HTTP
2. Based on the part of the config file you provided I can see that MongooseIM expects HTTP**S** traffic.

It looks like changing the endpoint in your `curl` command to `https://localhost:8089/api/rooms` will help. Of course, if you run the command on the same machine as MongooseIM is running. Otherwise, please change the `localhost` to a proper name or IP address of the machine.

What's more, in the config file I can see that the REST API is configured with the default, fake and self-signed certificates. I strongly encourage you to change it to real certificates. For the sake of testing, you will need to add the option `-k` to your `curl` command in order to skip cert verification.

Comment: Thanks for help @michalwski . Can't I test with self sign certificates with local setup

Comment: curl -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic dXNlckBsb2NhbGhvc3Q6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' 'https://localhost:8089/api/rooms' -k I put this way still now response This time no response.

Comment: How about this: `curl -k -v -X GET --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'Authorization: Basic dXNlckBsb2NhbGhvc3Q6cGFzc3dvcmQ=' 'https://localhost:8089/api/rooms'`

Comment: When I put this it gives 500 server error.  HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error

Comment: I have found the issue , mongooseim 3.3.0 not suport create group or get groups API. Thanks for Help

Comment: I tries the your request. It gives 500 error And this is the mongooseim server logs. mod_muc_light_db_backend:get_user_rooms Cowboy stream 1 with ranch listener 'ejabberd_cowboy_0.0.0.0_8089' and connection process <0.1399.0> had its request process exit with reason: call to undefined function mod_muc_light_db_backend:get_user_rooms({<<"sajith">>,<<"localhost">>}, undefined)